# How do I animate a strike through effect using JavaScript on a piece of text?

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to try create an effect where by when I trigger an event an animated line strikes through a piece of text. The effect should be done in Java Script.

Can someone suggest some ways to do this? I have text already on a page and I would like the text to strike through from left to right as if a line is being drawn

Comment: What mark-up are you working with? Vanilla JavaScript, or are you working with a library (jQuery, MooTools, Glow, Scriptaculous..)?

Comment: Not committed to any framework at the moment. Though would be nice to have it working with dojo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery it's  possible with little tweak: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/EbNh7/

JS in use:

```
var _text = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    _text = $("#myDiv").text();
    StrikeThrough(0);
});

function StrikeThrough(index) {
    if (index >= _text.length)
        return false;
    var sToStrike = _text.substr(0, index + 1);
    var sAfter = (index < (_text.length - 1)) ? _text.substr(index + 1, _text.length - index) : "";
    $("#myDiv").html("<strike>" + sToStrike + "</strike>" + sAfter);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        StrikeThrough(index + 1);
    }, 100);
}
```

This will strike through `myDiv` text, making the line appear with animation.

As it's not using any heavy jQuery stuff it can be converted to plain JavaScript pretty easily so if you prefer not to use jQuery I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is cool, but it might be better not to serialize the HTML with `html()` which will drop all other events attached.

Comment: @alex I assume there're no such events, just pulled quick example.. what might be better alternative IYO?

Comment: I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368521/how-do-i-animate-a-strike-through-effect-using-javascript-on-a-piece-of-text/5368711#5368711) myself.

Answer (score 4):

```
var findText = function(element, pattern, callback) {

    if ( ! element.childNodes) {
      return;   
    }
    for (var childi = element.childNodes.length; childi-- > 0;) {
        var child = element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType == 1) {
            findText(child, pattern, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            var matches = [];
            var match;
            while (match = pattern.exec(child.data))
            matches.push(match);
            for (var i = matches.length; i-- > 0;)
            callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
        }
    }
}


findText(document.body, /./g, function(node, match) {
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    node.splitText(match.index + 1);
    element.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(element, node.nextSibling);
});

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    spansLength = spans.length,
    currentSpan = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (currentSpan == spansLength) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        spans[currentSpan++].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

    }, 100);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wmBYx/).

- Go through each character (except `\n`) using regex and recursively apply function with callback to wrap each individual matched character with a `span`.
- Select all these `span` elements and then use `setInterval()` to traverse them, adding `style="text-decoration: line-through` via the `style` object of the `span`.
- Stop when we have iterated through each `span`.

The disadvantage of using `innerHTML` is when you serialize the HTML, you lose all events, etc. In the fiddle above, the `strong` element is still clickable (you will click the `span`, which will bubble up to the parent).

Comment: +1 of course, however I doubt the OP wants **all** text in the document to get striked out? :)

Comment: @Shadow The OP can simply change `document.body` to a whatever element they wish, and thank you very much.

Comment: sure, **I** know that.. :) Also, you're using `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` so this also need to be changed to support specific element.

Comment: @alex Isn't this a bit overkill? Please tell me what do you think of this:
1. Create a span before the text node with strikethrough.
2. Loop through the text, and move each of char to the new span by interval.
3. If the original element was a span, give it strikethrough and move all text back into it (to maintain events) and delete the new span. Othrwise that's it!

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery to animate a background image that looks like a strikethrough. Perhaps something like this:

```
$(".someclass").animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'})
```

This might look a little smoother than trying to do something involving `<s>` tags. Your HTML markup would be like this:

```
<span class="someclass">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

And you'd need to make sure that `.someclass` had default CSS that hid the background image by using background-position, ie:

```
.someclass { background-position: -1000px 0px; }
```

Comment: Nice idea. I don't think that would work across line breaks, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an empty span before the piece of text with a strikethrough style on it.  Then, I would write a function that pops the first character off the front of the piece of text and appends it to your span.  Then, use setTimeout() to call that function repeatedly until the piece of text is empty.

You asked for a suggestion - code would take longer :)

Comment: That's what I would do, but with `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Just came here from google, ended up writing my own simple little function. This is how I did it:

```
function drawLineOnClick() {

    //add or prepend div to the top of the div holding your text
    $("#IdOfElementHoldingTheText").prepend('<div id="lineThrough"></div>');
    var WidthStrikeThrEl = $("#IdOfElementHoldingTheText").width();

    $("#lineThrough").animate({width: WidthStrikeThrEl},1000, function() {

        //when line has been drawn, apply CSS line-through and remove line
        $("#IdOfElementHoldingTheText").attr('class', 'lineThrCssClass');
        $("#lineThrough").remove();
    });
}


#lineThrough {
  position:absolute;
  top:23px; //centering line over text to simulate actual line through
  width:0px;
  height:1px;
  background:#444; //color of line through
}

.lineThrCssClass {
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `<s>` tag to the beginning of the string and iteratively move the closing `</s>` tag one character further towards the end of the string, probably best using `setTimeout()`.

Something along these lines (not tested):

```
STRIKE_POS = 1;
ORIG_STR = '';

function startStrike(str) {
    STRIKE_POS = 1;
    ORIG_STR = str;
    strike();
}

function strike() {
    var str = '<s>' + ORIG_STR.substr(0, STRIKE_POS) + '</s>'
              + ORIG_STR.substr(STRIKE_POS);

    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE STRING, LIKE DISPLAY SOMEWHERE

    STRIKE_POS++;
    if (STRIKE_POS < ORIG_STR.length) {
        window.setTimeout("strike()", 200);    // adjust the timeout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation that works in current versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.gradualStrike = function(spanId, timeMillis) {
                var stepDuration;
                var strikeElem = document.getElementById(spanId);
                var strikeText = strikeElem.innerHTML.replace("<S>", "<s>").replace("</S>", "</s>");  //IE uppercases the tag
                var currentStrikePos = strikeText.indexOf("</s>");
                if (currentStrikePos < 0) {
                    currentStrikePos = 0;
                    stepDuration = timeMillis / strikeText.length;
                }
                else {
                    if (currentStrikePos + 3 == strikeText.length) {
                        //the '</s>' is at the end, we are done
                        return;
                    }
                    currentStrikePos -= 3; //account for the '<s>' tag
                    stepDuration = timeMillis / (strikeText.length - 7);  //account for '<s>' and '</s>'
                    strikeText = strikeText.replace("<s>", "").replace("</s>", ""); //strikeText.replace(/\<s\>/, "").replace(/\<\/s\>/, "");

                }
                currentStrikePos++;
                strikeText = "<s>" + strikeText.substring(0, currentStrikePos) + "</s>" + strikeText.substring(currentStrikePos);
                strikeElem.innerHTML = strikeText;
                setTimeout("gradualStrike('" + spanId + "', " + timeMillis + ");", stepDuration);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="someText" onclick="gradualStrike('someText', 1000); this.onclick=function(){return;};">Click to strike...</span>
    </body>
</html>
```