# Animate line-through text with CSS

Tags: css, animation, webkit, css-transitions

Is it possible to use Webkit animations/transitions to animate a strikethrough line going through a word from left to right? As far as I can tell, I can only make it fade in/out, not animate it striking the text out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in CSS can do this. Also, if you're considering JavaScript this may be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368521/how-do-i-animate-a-strike-through-effect-using-javascript-on-a-piece-of-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works.. (I used hover, not sure what event you want it to trigger)

html:

```
<p>This is <span class='line_wrap'><span class='line'></span>weird</span></p>​
```

css:

```
span.line_wrap {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;        
}
span.line {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    width:0;
    border-top:1px solid grey;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
}
span.line_wrap:hover span.line {
    width:100%;    
}​
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/LXKJU/

**EDIT:** This is really just to illustrate it's *possible*... makes horrible markup though. I wouldn't advise you to use it...

**EDIT 2:** Or triggered with Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/bendog/Kdd7K/

Comment: Ben, the two jsfiddle snippets are the same. I don't want to give you extra work so if you still have that javascript implementation, I'd appreciate it. If not, it's ok.

Comment: @Ashitaka.. mmm, that's weird, not sure why it's gone from jsfiddle. I don't have it anymore, just experimented in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Ashitaka .. but basically you'll want change the :hover to a custom class and add that custom class on the fly with JS..