# Strike through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to strike through content on my webpage. Some of the content is text, other is links, ... and **I need a function that can just strike through it**.

Found this great answer: [How do I animate a strike through effect using JavaScript on a piece of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368521/how-do-i-animate-a-strike-through-effect-using-javascript-on-a-piece-of-text)   (2nd answer)
But I want to transform it into a function, so that I can use it a bit everywhere.

His original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wmBYx/

Here is his JS:

```
var findText = function(element, pattern, callback) {

    if ( ! element.childNodes) {
      return;   
    }
    for (var childi = element.childNodes.length; childi-- > 0;) {
        var child = element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType == 1) {
            findText(child, pattern, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            var matches = [];
            var match;
            while (match = pattern.exec(child.data))
            matches.push(match);
            for (var i = matches.length; i-- > 0;)
            callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
        }
    }
}


findText(document.body, /./g, function(node, match) {
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    node.splitText(match.index + 1);
    element.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(element, node.nextSibling);
});

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    spansLength = spans.length,
    currentSpan = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (currentSpan == spansLength) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        spans[currentSpan++].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

    }, 100);
```

To tell you the truth, I don't understand any of it, so I have no idea how I can transform this into a DRY function. (Won't even show you what I got so far, I'm ashamed).

Thanks for your help

PS: I'm using jquery, so you are more than welcome to add some in it.

Comment: Unless you want all text nodes in your page to get striked through, change `document.body` to `this[0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a jQuery plugin for it:

```
$.fn.strikeThrough = (function() {

    var findText = function(element, pattern, callback) {

        if ( ! element.childNodes) {
          return;   
        }

        for (var childi = element.childNodes.length; childi-- > 0;) {
            var child = element.childNodes[childi];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                findText(child, pattern, callback);
            } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                var matches = [];
                var match;
                while (match = pattern.exec(child.data))
                matches.push(match);
                for (var i = matches.length; i-- > 0;)
                callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return function(pattern) {
        pattern = pattern || /./g;

        if (this.length > 1) {
            this.each(function() {
                $(this).strikeThrough(pattern);
            });
            return this;
        }

        findText(document.body, pattern, function(node, match) {
            var element = document.createElement('span');
            node.splitText(match.index + 1);
            element.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(element, node.nextSibling);
        });

        var spans = this[0].getElementsByTagName('span'),
            spansLength = spans.length,
            currentSpan = 0,
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (currentSpan == spansLength) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                }
                spans[currentSpan++].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

            }, 100);

        return this;
    };

})();

$(function() {
    $('div').strikeThrough();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>strike me out please but <strong>don't</strong> drop my events!</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmBYx/19/)

Answer (score -2):

This is incredibly simple.

```
$(function(){
    //pass over the jQuery object.
    strikeThrough($('.ele'));
});

/*
 * Create function outside of .ready() scope
 */
function strikeThrough(ele){
    ele.css('textDecoration', 'line-through');  
}
```

[And here is the working jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/PdGqJ/)

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy, might have forgotten to mention that this has an animation.