# jQuery - once item is clicked, grab data-item for li and apply a strike through to text in li (animate?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of images that correspond to a list containing their names.
When the image is clicked it fades out the image then using data-item finds its corresponding name on the list and then crosses it out in red and changes the list item word to grey. I have code but it is not working or throwing any errors in console. I am new to jQuery.

How would I connect the clicked image with the correct list name and then change the font color to grey and give it a different color (red) strike through? I'd love to animate the strike through but that may be too involved. Advice is welcome :)

Any help is appreciated!

Here is a snippet of the code:

**CSS**

```
.stroked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}

.found {
  color: #282828!important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--image items-->
<div class="picItem" data-item="Dart">
  <img src="Dart.png" />
</div>

<div class="picItem" data-item="Dice">
  <img src="Dice.png" />
</div>

<div class="itemWrapper">
  <ul class="itemList">
    <li class="olive">Olive</li>
    <li class="dart">Dart</li>
    <li class="dice">Dice</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /itemWrapper -->
```

**JS**

```
 // Handle the picture item clicks
$('.picItem').on('click', function () {

 //grab appropriate list item view data-item for strikeThrough function
  strikeThrough($(this).data('item'));

  $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
  });
});


 function strikeThrough() {
     if ($('.itemList li').hasClass('stroked')) {
      return;
  } else {
      $(this).addClass('stroked');
      $(this).addClass('found');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to add arg in the strikeThrough function definition
2. You cannot use `this` object as the function is called on window scope, so the this would be referring to window object inside strikeThrough function. You could use `.call` or `.apply` to set the scope, but I don't see a need for it.
3. Changed the `data-item` to match the class name of the each `li`

**PS:** Your question and your code speaks differently, so check out the demo and let me know your comments.

```js
// Handle the picture item clicks
$('.picItem').on('click', function() {

  //grab appropriate list item view data-item for strikeThrough function
  strikeThrough($(this).data('item'));

  $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {});
});


function strikeThrough(item) {
  var $item = $('.itemList li.' + item);
  if ($item.hasClass('stroked')) { //already stroked
    return;
  } else {
    $item.addClass('stroked').prepend('<span class="linethrough">       </span>').find('span').css('width', $item.width()).addClass('movein');
  }
}
```

```css
.stroked {
    color: #282828;
    position: relative;
}
.linethrough {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    white-space: pre;
    color: red;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
    -o-transition: left 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 1s ease;
    transition: left 1s ease;
}
.linethrough.movein {
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picItem" data-item="dart">
  <img src="Dart.png" alt="Dart" />
</div>

<div class="picItem" data-item="dice">
  <img src="Dice.png" alt="Dice" />
</div>

<div class="itemWrapper">
  <ul class="itemList">
    <li class="olive">Olive</li>
    <li class="dart">Dart</li>
    <li class="dice">Dice</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh.. you have to connect the strikeThrough function TO the item. This appears to work but the font color of the list item turns grey and so does the strikethrough. How would I make the strike through red and the word under it grey? Thanks!

Comment: @user826345 The strike through and the text are part of the same text. Strike through is just a style applied to the text, I don't think you can have different colors. However, it is possible but with an expensive markup and script.

Comment: Thanks, Vega! I found this on changing strikethrough color : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text I'll give it a try. Thanks again or your help :)

Comment: @user826345 That looks interesting, I will check and will see if I can animate the same.

Comment: @user826345 I worked through some animation with minimal changes and CSS. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: Wow! That is so SHINY! ~applauds~ +1

Answer (score 1):

The argument you passed through on the top will also have to be defined as a parameter of your `strikeThrough()` function so you can make use of that when defining which element to strike through.

So replace your `strikeThrough()` function like this:

```
function strikeThrough(obj) {
 $('.itemList li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == obj)
          $(this).addClass('stroked').addClass('found');
 });
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ph5z3pwx/

For the strikethrough effect, have a look into this question: [How do I animate a strike through effect using JavaScript on a piece of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368521/how-do-i-animate-a-strike-through-effect-using-javascript-on-a-piece-of-text)

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the animation link. I'll check it out! I also appreciate seeing a different way to solve this. +1